# Persisting uid from facebook omniauth response - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to update my Devise model `Vendor` with the uid returned from Facebook via omniauth. This isn't a sign in or sign up for my app, but rather an integration with Facebook if that makes sense. I'm trying to use this pattern:

```
class Vendors::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @vendor = current_vendor
        uid = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["uid"]
        puts uid
        @vendor.update_attributes(:uid => uid)
        redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path
    end
end
```

I keep getting 302 Found when this method tries to update the attributes. When I `puts uid` I see the correct uid getting returned, but the params hash is made up of a `state` and `code` attribute. What am I not understanding about this callback method?

Server log:

```
Processing by Vendors::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "state"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
  Vendor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 25 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/vendors/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 152ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

Comment: Your route should handle the vendor callback routing

Comment: did you missed some setting in facebook as even  facebook needs to know about your app...check the settings!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting blocked by the built in Mass-assignment protection, try updating just the column with update_column and see if that solves your issue. Since AR has basically the same model it began with, the commit does not write anything back to the database.

Try the following:

```
class Vendors::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @vendor = current_vendor
        uid = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["uid"]
        puts uid
        @vendor.update_column(:uid, uid)
        redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path
    end
end
```